# Why does dropping a single point dramatically affect location of polygon centroid?

Tags: python, shapely, centroids

I'm a relative novice working with some coordinate data using shapely and have found a weird behavior when trying to identify outlier points. The approach I am using is to iterate over a series of points creating a Polygon using all but the current point in the iteration, and then to calculate the distance from the current point to the centroid of the Polygon created in step 2. Any point significantly further from the centroid of the others than the mean of those distances is considered an outlier.

One case has yielded strange results. The points are as follows, all relatively close together:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely import wkt

p = ['POINT Z (28.219403 -9.360669 0)', 
     'POINT Z (28.3255635 -9.280321799999999 0)', 
     'POINT Z (28.219435 -9.360731700000001 0)',
     'POINT Z (28.2077176 -9.442305599999999 0)', 
     'POINT Z (28.3244627 -9.286111200000001 0)', 
     'POINT Z (28.2191343 -9.360647500000001 0)']
```

When you compute the centroid of the polygon with all of them included, the answer is very reasonable.

```
>>> p = [wkt.loads(x) for x in p]
>>> Polygon(p).centroid.xy
(array('d', [28.250548831170587]), array('d', [-9.362973996290707]))
```

But when you run the same calculation dropping the third point in the list, the resulting centroid is incredibly far away from all of the other points.

```
>>> p_prime = ['POINT Z (28.219403 -9.360669 0)', 
               'POINT Z (28.3255635 -9.280321799999999 0)', 
               # 'POINT Z (28.219435 -9.360731700000001 0)',
               'POINT Z (28.2077176 -9.442305599999999 0)', 
               'POINT Z (28.3244627 -9.286111200000001 0)', 
               'POINT Z (28.2191343 -9.360647500000001 0)']

>>> p_prime = [wkt.loads(x) for x in p_prime]
>>> Polygon(p_prime).centroid.xy
(array('d', [-6.857533437170832]), array('d', [-191.95569600984862]))
```

If you drop any of the other points, the result is around `(28.3, -9.3)`. Just this single point seems to throw off the calculation.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it in the future?

Comment: Please plot your polygons so you can check their shape visually. Perhaps that gives a hint. Check also that polygon remains valid and does not have self-intersection.

Comment: This seems to be the issue, thanks! Do you have any suggestions as to how to calculate the center of a group of points that don't make a valid polygon? In ideal circumstances these points would all be the same, so self-intersection is a concern here

Comment: You can use `MultiPoint` (instead of `Polygon`) to calculate the center of a group of points.

Comment: There also may be an issue with the definition of "centroid", since the center of mass can be outside the figure (doughnut), while a label point is  is likely to be required to be *within* the feature.

Comment: Thanks, all! @KadirŞahbaz I think using ```MultiPoint``` is the way to go. Makes much more sense than hoping that the shape formed by the points fits the ```Polygon``` requirements. Can you post that as an answer so I can choose it?